# Как установить 10 ботов telegram на одном сервере vps c вебхуками и какие требования к серверу?

Tags: telegram-bot

Требуется запустить 10 ботов для мессенджера Telegram. На вебхуках. Пробовал CherryPy, но виснет все из за этого. И какие требования нужны к серверу?

Comment: Очевидно зависит от собственно ботов, но скорее всего требования очень маленькие, а вы просто чего-то не осилили

Comment: Сервер 256 мегабайт и постоянно приходят сообщения, что нехватка оперативной памяти. Собственно дело больше в другом через cherrypy можно установить 4 бота максимум потому что доступно всего 4 порта и то при условии что они не заняты.

Comment: Если не принципиально использовать вебхуки - можно лонгполами, тогда вам даже сервер не понадобится. Пример на js, работающий прямо с веб страницы http://vladimirgamalian.github.io/TheTurkBot/